# best time to buy and sell stock dynamic programming

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Trying to solve [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-iii/description/): Say you have an array for which the ith element is the price of a given stock on day i.

Design an algorithm to find the maximum profit. You may complete at most two transactions.

Solution:
What i am doing is divide and conquer kind of approach.

*dp[i][j]* is the maximum profit between *ith* and *jth* day.Calculated as below:

*dp[i][j] = max(dp[i][j], max(prices[i] - prices[j], dp[k][j], dp[i][k+1]))*, where k is less than i and greater than j.

Now all we need is below to find out the maximum profit in two transactions:

*m = max(m, max(dp[i][j], dp[k][j] + dp[i][k+1]))*

Please give me **just hint** to solve this problem as the existing solution presented here is timing out.

```
class Solution(object):
    def profit(self, prices, dp):
        m = 0
        for w in range(1, len(prices)):
            for i in range(1, len(prices)):
                for j in range(i-w, i):
                    if i-w < 0:
                        continue
                    for k in range(j, i):
                        dp[i][j] = max(dp[i][j], max(prices[i] - prices[j], dp[k][j], dp[i][k+1]))
                        m = max(m, max(dp[i][j], dp[k][j] + dp[i][k+1]))
        return m

    def maxProfit(self, prices):
        """
        :type prices: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        dp = [[0 for i in range(len(prices)+1)] for i in range(len(prices)+1)]
        return self.profit(prices, dp)
```

Comment: Do you mean the max profit if you buy first and sell later? Because otherwise it's just the min and the max.

Comment: @Carlos: yes, buy first and then sell later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint would be to pre-process the prices and find out the maximum profit that can be earnt by selling at a price ending at index i. 
Then, you can start from end of the pre-process vector to find out the solution to the problem.  This will solve the problem using 1-D DP and will not time out.

```
  int maxProfit(vector<int>& prices) {

    int mprof = 0;
    if (prices.size()>1){
        int maxprof = 0;
        vector<int> mp; // max profit before each element
        mp.push_back(0);
        int st = *prices.begin();
        for(int i = 1 ; i<=prices.size();i++){  //compute mp vector
            if (mprof < prices[i]-st){mprof = prices[i]-st;}
            if (prices[i]<st){st = prices[i];}
            mp.push_back(mprof);
        }
        mprof = 0;
        int ed = *(prices.end()-1);
        for (int i = prices.size()-2; i>=0; i--){
            if (mprof < ed - prices[i] + mp[i]) { mprof = ed - prices[i] + mp[i];}
            if (prices[i]>ed) {ed = prices[i];}
        }
    }
    return mprof;

}
```

Comment: Prefix-sum + Kadane's algorithm?

Comment: It will not be prefix sum exactly as the profit will not be the prefix sum always.

Comment: @PriyanshGoel: I solved it other way i.e. by tracking the maximum profit till i from left and maximum profit till i from right. Add up both the left and right profits in 0(n). Can you suggest your solution now?

Comment: @nomanpouigt : I am doing the same thing without maintaining a right array. You can do that in left array only.

Comment: @PriyanshGoel: possible to post some pseudo code for that?

Comment: @nomanpouigt : I have added the code for your reference. Also, please accept the answer as it works for you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
class Solution:
    def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
        if len(prices) <= 1:
            return 0

        max_profit = 0
        buy_price = prices[0]
        for price in prices:
            if price >= buy_price:
                max_profit += price - buy_price
                buy_price = price
            else:
                buy_price = price


        return max_profit
```

Comment: Runtime, memory-optimized the pythonic solution!